# Visual Studio 2013 start profiling greyed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I used to work with the built in profiler of Visual Studio once in a while and found it a very useful tool.

Now, I can't do this, because the menu items "Start profiling" and "Start profiling paused" under Analyze->Profiler are greyed out.

It's a Windows Form Solution.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 /
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 /
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51650

Comment: That happens, depends on the project type.   Don't make us guess.  The profiler has always been a weak spot, big changes in VS2015.

Comment: Restart VS. That worked when I had this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open performance explorer window (`analyze -> windows -> performance explorer`) and see if you have selected any target.

If not add your windows forms project as target (right click on "Targets" and follow menus) than you should be able to start profiling.

EDIT: Be sure to include your start up project as one of the Targets. You can right click this target and uncheck "collect samples" if you don't want sample data from this project.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me choosing

> Debug->Start Diagnostic Tools without debugging(Alt+F2)

menu option. This will bring the Performance Wizard and from there you can continue doing what you want.